# Warning when i'm trying to install Android on NetBeans 7.2 Beta

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I'm trying to Use `android` with `Netbeans` , but every time i try to do it , it gave me warning message Like this:

[image]

Exactly what i do :

- Tools -> Plugins ->Settings tab  ->press `Add` button and fill name "NBAndroid" and URL "http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/updatecenter/updates.xml"

then i get the above warning  Message

It's my first time to try it , and googled it but didn't find any thing ,So i need the help for do that , thank you

Comment: @downvoter : seriously !! at least say why downvote it will be better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I found the solution :

According to [Installation using AutoUpdate center](http://www.nbandroid.org/p/installation.html)

> address of our update center that is:
>
> - http://nbandroid.org/release72/updates/updates.xml if you run NetBeans 7.2 or newer Previous update center at
> - http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/updatecenter/updates.xml
>     is removed now as it caused confusion about current version and what
>     is supported and what not.`///////////and this is was my problem , so
>     i used the first one , and it's ok now`